# Does NDepend run on Mono/Linux?

Tags: linux, mono, ndepend

I'd like to use [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) at home for an open source project, but I can't find if it run on linux with mono 2.6.8.

Any one have succesfully used it on a mono only machine?

Answer (score 1):

The console version *may* work.  The GUI version definitely won't.

Comment: It do not work. I got ArgumentException since the absolute path doesn't begin with a single letter drive followed by ":\".

Answer (score 0):

NDepend reads the IL code in the dll's.

If you have a windows machine you could copy the dll's to the windows machine and run the analysis there.

Answer (score 0):

Since version 2021.2 NDepend analysis and reporting can run on Linux and macOS upon the `net5.0` runtime (`net6.0`, `net7.0` runtimes supported soon).

See this documentation to get started: [Getting Started with NDepend on Linux and macOS](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/getting-started-with-ndepend-linux-macos)